# Retrieve Object from Json in Apache Camel

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, apache-camel

I'm using `Apache Camel` and `Spring Boot` to build a servlet service. I have a REST endpoint where I receive json objects. I want to read the json and map it into a POJO in my code. Here's my **RouteBuilder**:

```
public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder{

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

    restConfiguration()
     .component("servlet")
     .host("localhost")
     .port("8080")
     .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto);

    rest("/say").post("/json").type(User.class).to("direct:json");
    from("direct:json").someUsefulMethod();
    }
}
```

Here's my **User class**:

```
public class User {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

I followed [the Apache documentation](http://camel.apache.org/rest-dsl.html).
What I want to do is to inject a json like {"id":"123", "name":"elly", "age":"29"} into an instance of my User class. How do I take the data from the REST request? 
Thank all of you.

*EDIT AFTER ANSWER:* for completeness this is the final example code in `MyRouteBuilder` class:

```
    from("direct:json").process(new Processor() {
       public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
          User body = exchange.getIn().getBody(User.class);
          System.out.println("Input object: " + body.getName() + ", " + body.getAge());
          body.setAge("35");
          exchange.getIn().setBody(body);
          System.out.println("Output object: " + body.getName() + ", " + body.getAge());
       }
});
```

Comment: Add camel-jackson to the classpath so it can bind json to pojo. See some of  the rest examples at: https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples

Comment: That did the trick. If you put your comment as an answer I can choose it as correct answer. Thanks so much :)

Comment: This approach always ends in a `null` body for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add camel-jackson to the classpath so it can bind json to pojo.

See some of the rest examples at:
https://github.com/apache/camel-examples/tree/master/examples

You can use jackson annotations on your POJOs to fine tune the binding

Comment: That is correct, I had to esplicitate the camel-jackson dependency, the spring boot jackson dependency wasn't enough.